# RNGE Physics update speed during game

Tags: javascript, reactjs, physics

I´m doing a flappy-bird game in React Native Game Engine (RNGE), and I´m looking for a way to update the speed throughout the game so the game gets more and more difficult.

The speed is commented below where you define the speed of the pipes moving to the left. I have tried to use context with hooks but the game crashes with the error message 'Invalid hook call' as the Physics function gets called at deltatime, if I understand it correctly(?).

Any pro tip for what I can try?

I just started using RNGE, so I really appreciate all the help I can get!

```
import React from "react";
import Matter from "matter-js";

const Physics = (entities, { touches, time }) => {
  let engine = entities.physics.engine;
  let bird = entities.bird.body;

  touches
    .filter((t) => t.type === "press")
    .forEach((t) => {
      Matter.Body.setVelocity(bird, {
        x: bird.velocity.x,
        y: -5,
      });
    });

  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    //if the pipe is moving off the screen, change x-position to the right again
    if (
      entities["pipe" + i].body.position.x <=
      -1 * (Constants.PIPE_WIDTH / 2)
    ) {
      Matter.Body.setPosition(entities["pipe" + i].body, {
        x: Constants.MAX_WIDTH * 2 - Constants.PIPE_WIDTH / 2,
        y: entities["pipe" + i].body.position.y,
      });
    } else {
      //change pipe-position in delta time updates
      Matter.Body.translate(entities["pipe" + i].body, {
        x: -1, //need this value to slowly decrease during the game so the pipes move faster
        y: 0,
      }); 
    }
  }

  Matter.Engine.update(engine, time.delta);
  return entities;
};

export default Physics;
```